# Unable to link find libraries when linking

Tags: gcc, linker

When I link the .ld file using gcc I got the following error

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lreadline
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

my run.sh scripts contains the following command
rm  *.o *.bin *.iso
rm -rf isodir

## assemble boot.s file

```
as --32 boot.s -o boot.o
```

## linking the kernel with kernel.o and boot.o files

```
gcc  -m32  -lunistd -Wno-unused-result -c kernelCheck.c -o kernel.o -std=gnu99 -ffreestanding -flto -O2 -Wall -Wextra  -L/usr/lib -fno-exceptions 



gcc -m32  -T linker.ld -o MoraWing.bin -ffreestanding -Wl,--build-id=none  -O2 -nostdlib boot.o kernel.o -lgcc
```

grub-file --is-x86-multiboot MoraWing.bin

## building the iso file

```
mkdir -p isodir/boot/grub

cp MoraWing.bin isodir/boot/MoraWing.bin

cp grub.cfg isodir/boot/grub/grub.cfg
grub-mkrescue -o MoraWing.iso ./isodir
```

## run it in qemu

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -cdrom MoraWing.iso
```

Comment: Do you have `/usr/lib/libreadline.so` or `/usr/lib64/libreadline.so`?

Comment: And what is the `.ld` file?

Comment: I could find it following locations                                                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so                                                                               I have installed the libreadline-dev library

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `libreadline-dev`, or a similar package suitable for your system (you should also specify *what* your system is).

Comment: yes I  have installed the library.I'm using ubuntu 16.04

Comment: What is your *complete* link command? Please edit your question with updates.